# "If you pay for my ticket then we will be quits." -- what's the meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I just came across the following sentence;

> If you pay for my ticket then we will be [quits](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quilt?q=quilts).

What does the phrase ***"we will be quits"*** mean in there? Please, elaborate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dictionary, *be quits* [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quits?q=be%20quits):

"to not owe money to someone or to each other now"

> If you pay for my ticket then we will be quits

will then mean that the subject in the sentence will not owe money to the speaker if he pays for his ticket.

Comment: So, quits in this context is used as an adjective. Uh! I thought it be used as a plural noun, that assumption of mine created confusion. "Am I quits with you now?" ^^

Comment: Precisely, as an adjective.